# I now am getting this error "The type initializer for 'iTrac.SalesOrder' threw an exception."

Tags: vb.net

I have a function that works fine `iTrac.SalesOrder.SalesOrdersByBody_JB`, when I try to call it from the web service, it fails and throws the exception

> "The type initializer for 'iTrac.SalesOrder' threw an exception."

I see this is a fairly common situation and I did go through ALL of the similar questions but I did not see any answer to my problem, or maybe I am too much of a newbie to recognize the answer...?

went through all the similar questions.

```
Private Sub BrowserMailSender(obj As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim x As New List(Of iTrac.JBSODetail)
    Try
        FileIO.WriteToFile("service is started:" + Now + vbNewLine)
        x = iTrac.SalesOrder.SalesOrdersByBody_JB(241)
        FileIO.WriteToFile(x.ToString)
    Catch ex As Exception
        FileIO.WriteToFile(ex.Message + vbNewLine)
    End Try

End Sub
```

function that throws the exception

```
Public Shared Function SalesOrdersByBody_JB(ByVal BodyID As String) As List(Of JBSODetail)

    Dim SalesOrderList As New List(Of JBSODetail)
    Using context = New iTracContext
        Dim BOMList = New List(Of Integer)
        Dim StatusList As New List(Of String)
        BOMList = context.BillOfMaterials.Where(Function(b) b.Child = 
                  BodyID And b.ParentClass = "RTS").Select(Function(b) 
                                                    b.Parent).ToList

        If BOMList Is Nothing Then
            Return Nothing
        Else
            StatusList.Add("OPEN")
            StatusList.Add("HOLD")
            StatusList.Add("BACKORDER")
        End If
        Dim query =context.JBSODetails.Include
                   ("Part").Include("SOHeader").AsQueryable
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(BodyID) Then
            query = query.Where(Function(s) 
                    BOMList.Contains(s.pid) And 
                    StatusList.Contains(s.status.ToUpper))
        End If

        Return query.OrderBy(Function(s) s.promised_date).ToList

    End Using

End Function
```

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
Imports iTrac

<Table("tblSODetails")>
Public Class SalesOrder

    <Key()>
    Public Property sid As Decimal
    Public Property SalesOrderNumber As String
    Public Property SalesOrderLine As String
    Public Property NeedDate As Date
    Public Property PromisedDate As Date
    Public Property ShipTo As String
    Public Property Customer As String
    <Column("UnitPriceOfOrder")>
    Public Property UnitPrice As Decimal?
    <Column("PriceUnitOfOrder")>
    Public Property PriceUnit As String
    Public Property OrderQuantity As Decimal?
    Public Property OrderBalance As Decimal?
    Public Property OrderEntryDate As Date
    <Column("Material")>
    Public Property CustomerPartNumber As String
    Public Property LastUpdated As Date
    Public Property CustomerPO As String
    <NotMapped()>
    Public Property NormalizedPartNumber As String
    Public Property OfficeNote As String

    Public Property pid As Integer?
    Public Property aid As Integer?
    Public Property cid As Integer?
    Public Property TransferTime As Date
    Public Property ShipVia As String

    <NotMapped>
    Public Property RunningTotal As Integer?

    <ForeignKey("pid")>
    Public Property Inventory As CompiledInventory

    <ForeignKey("pid")>
    Public Property Part As Part

    <NotMapped()>
    Public Property RTS
    <NotMapped()>
    Public Property Plate
    <NotMapped()>
    Public Property Machined

    <NotMapped()>
    Public Property Status

    Private Shared ConnectionString As String = BrowserUtilities.Settings.ConnectionString

    Public ReadOnly Property Blocked As Boolean
        Get
            Return ShippingBlock.BlockExists(SalesOrderNumber, SalesOrderLine)
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Shared Function OpenSalesOrderList(ByVal CustomerName As String,
                                                ByVal ShipToAddress As String,
                                                ByVal CustomerPartNumber As String,
                                                ByVal CutOffDate As String,
                                                ByVal NormalizedID As String,
                                                ByVal UpdatedWindow As String,
                                                Optional ByVal CustomerPO As String = "") As List(Of SalesOrder)

        Dim SalesOrderList As New List(Of SalesOrder)

        Using Connection As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)

            Connection.Open()

            Dim sqlString = ""
            Dim sqlWhereClause = ""
            If CustomerName <> "" Then
                sqlWhereClause = " where customer = '" & CustomerName & "'"
            End If

            If ShipToAddress <> "" Then
                If sqlWhereClause > "" Then
                    sqlWhereClause += " and shipto = '"
                Else
                    sqlWhereClause += " where shipto = '"
                End If
                sqlWhereClause += ShipToAddress + "'"
            End If

            If CustomerPartNumber <> "" Then
                If sqlWhereClause > "" Then
                    sqlWhereClause += " and material like '"
                Else
                    sqlWhereClause += " where material like '"
                End If
                sqlWhereClause += CustomerPartNumber + "'"
            End If

            If CustomerPO <> "" Then
                If sqlWhereClause > "" Then
                    sqlWhereClause += " and customerpo = '"
                Else
                    sqlWhereClause += " where customerpo = '"
                End If
                sqlWhereClause += CustomerPO + "'"
            End If

            If NormalizedID <> "" Then
                If NormalizedID <> "0" Then
                    If sqlWhereClause > "" Then
                        sqlWhereClause += " and pid = '"
                    Else
                        sqlWhereClause += " where pid = '"
                    End If
                    sqlWhereClause += NormalizedID + "'"
                End If
            End If

            If CutOffDate <> "" And CustomerPO = "" Then
                If sqlWhereClause > "" Then
                    sqlWhereClause += " and promiseddate <= '"
                Else
                    sqlWhereClause += " where promiseddate <= '"
                End If
                sqlWhereClause += CutOffDate + "'"
            End If

            If UpdatedWindow <> "" Then
                If sqlWhereClause > "" Then
                    sqlWhereClause += " and "
                Else
                    sqlWhereClause += "where "
                End If
                sqlWhereClause += "lastupdated between '" & Now.AddHours(-Val(UpdatedWindow)) & "' and '" & Now & "'"
            End If

            sqlString = "Select s.*, (select NormalizedPartNumber from tblPart where id = pid) as NormalizedPartNumber from tblSODetails as s" & sqlWhereClause
            If UpdatedWindow <> "" Then
                sqlString += " order by customer, normalizedpartnumber, promiseddate"
            Else
                sqlString += " order by promiseddate"
            End If

            Dim command = New SqlCommand(sqlString, Connection)

            Dim dataReader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()

            While dataReader.Read()
                Dim so = New SalesOrder()
                so.MapDataReader(dataReader, 1)
                SalesOrderList.Add(so)
            End While

        End Using

        Return SalesOrderList

    End Function

    Private Sub MapDataReader(ByVal dataReader As IDataReader, ByVal Method As Integer)

        Select Case Method
            Case 0, 1
                sid = If(IsDBNull(dataReader("sid")), "", dataReader("sid"))
                SalesOrderNumber = If(IsDBNull(dataReader("salesordernumber")), "", dataReader("salesordernumber"))
                SalesOrderLine = If(IsDBNull(dataReader("salesorderline")), "", dataReader("salesorderline"))
                PromisedDate = If(IsDBNull(dataReader("promiseddate")), "", dataReader("promiseddate"))
                ShipTo = If(IsDBNull(dataReader("shipto")), "", dataReader("shipto"))
                Customer = If(IsDBNull(dataReader("customer")), "", dataReader("customer"))
                UnitPrice = If(IsDBNull(dataReader("unitpriceoforder")), 0, dataReader("unitpriceoforder"))
                PriceUnit = If(IsDBNull(dataReader("priceunitoforder")), "", dataReader("priceunitoforder"))
                OrderQuantity = If(IsDBNull(dataReader("orderquantity")), "", dataReader("orderquantity"))
                OrderBalance = If(IsDBNull(dataReader("orderbalance")), "", dataReader("orderbalance"))
                OrderEntryDate = If(IsDBNull(dataReader("orderentrydate")), "", dataReader("orderentrydate"))
                CustomerPartNumber = If(IsDBNull(dataReader("material")), "", dataReader("material"))
                LastUpdated = If(IsDBNull(dataReader("lastupdated")), "", dataReader("lastupdated"))
                CustomerPO = If(IsDBNull(dataReader("customerpo")), "", dataReader("customerpo"))
                OfficeNote = If(IsDBNull(dataReader("officenote")), "", dataReader("officenote"))
                pid = If(IsDBNull(dataReader("pid")), 0, dataReader("pid"))
                aid = If(IsDBNull(dataReader("aid")), 0, dataReader("aid"))
                cid = If(IsDBNull(dataReader("cid")), 0, dataReader("cid"))
                TransferTime = dataReader("transfertime")
                ShipVia = If(IsDBNull(dataReader("shipvia")), "", dataReader("shipvia"))
                NeedDate = If(IsDBNull(dataReader("new_promised_date")), dataReader("promiseddate"), dataReader("new_promised_date"))
                If Method = 1 Then NormalizedPartNumber = If(IsDBNull(dataReader("normalizedpartnumber")), "", dataReader("normalizedpartnumber"))
            Case 2
                Customer = If(IsDBNull(dataReader("customer")), "Unknown", dataReader("customer"))
        End Select

    End Sub

    Public Shared Function SalesOrdersByBody(ByVal BodyID As String, ByVal CustomerPartNumber As String) As List(Of SalesOrder)

        Dim SalesOrderList As New List(Of SalesOrder)
        Dim CP As New Part
        Using Connection As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)

            Dim sqlString = ""
            Connection.Open()

            If BodyID > "" Then
                sqlString = "Select s.*, d.new_promised_date from tblPart as p " &
                "inner join tblSODetails as s on p.id = s.pid " &
                "inner join tblJBSODetails d on d.sales_order = s.salesordernumber " &
                "inner join tblBillOfMaterial as b on p.id = b.parent and parentclass = 'rts' " &
                "where b.child = " & BodyID & " order by s.promiseddate"
            Else
                sqlString = "Select s.*, d.new_promised_date from tblPart as p " &
                "inner join tblSODetails as s on s.pid = p.id " &
                "inner join tblJBSODetails d on d.sales_order = s.salesordernumber " &
                "where p.CustomerPartNumber = '" & CustomerPartNumber & "' " &
                "order by s.promiseddate"
            End If

            Dim command = New SqlCommand(sqlString, Connection)

            Dim dataReader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()

            While dataReader.Read()
                Dim so = New SalesOrder()
                so.MapDataReader(dataReader, 0)
                SalesOrderList.Add(so)
            End While

        End Using

        Return SalesOrderList

    End Function
    Public Shared Function SalesOrdersByBody_JB(ByVal BodyID As String) As List(Of JBSODetail)

        Dim SalesOrderList As New List(Of JBSODetail)
        Using context = New iTracContext
            Dim BOMList = New List(Of Integer)
            Dim StatusList As New List(Of String)
            BOMList = context.BillOfMaterials.Where(Function(b) b.Child = BodyID And b.ParentClass = "RTS").Select(Function(b) b.Parent).ToList

            If BOMList Is Nothing Then
                Return Nothing
            Else
                StatusList.Add("OPEN")
                StatusList.Add("HOLD")
                StatusList.Add("BACKORDER")
            End If
            Dim query = context.JBSODetails.Include("Part").Include("SOHeader").AsQueryable
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(BodyID) Then
                query = query.Where(Function(s) BOMList.Contains(s.pid) And StatusList.Contains(s.status.ToUpper))
            End If
            Return query.OrderBy(Function(s) s.promised_date).ToList

        End Using

    End Function


    Public Shared Function SalesOrdersByPartID(ByVal PartID As Integer) As List(Of SalesOrder)

        Dim SalesOrderList As New List(Of SalesOrder)

        Using Connection As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)

            Dim sqlString = ""
            Connection.Open()

            sqlString = "Select s.*, d.new_promised_date from tblPart as p " &
            "inner join tblSODetails as s on p.id = s.pid " &
            "inner join tblJBSODetails d on d.sales_order = s.salesordernumber " &
            "inner join tblBillOfMaterial as b on p.id = b.parent and parentclass = 'rts' " &
            "where b.parent = " & PartID & " order by s.promiseddate"


            Dim command = New SqlCommand(sqlString, Connection)

            Dim dataReader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()

            While dataReader.Read()
                Dim so = New SalesOrder()
                so.MapDataReader(dataReader, 0)
                SalesOrderList.Add(so)
            End While

        End Using

        Return SalesOrderList
        'Using context = New iTracContext
        '    Return context.SalesOrders.Where(Function(s) s.pid = PartID).ToList
        'End Using
    End Function
    Public Shared Function SalesOrdersByPartID_JB(ByVal PartID As Integer) As List(Of JBSODetail)
        Dim SalesOrderList As New List(Of JBSODetail)
        Using context = New iTracContext
            Dim query = context.JBSODetails.Include("SOHeader").Include("Part").AsQueryable
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(PartID) Then query = query.Where(Function(s) s.pid = PartID)
            query = query.Where(Function(s) s.status = "Open")
            Return query.OrderBy(Function(s) s.promised_date).ToList
        End Using

    End Function
    Public Function CustomerList(ByVal CutoffDate As Date) As List(Of String)

        Dim CList As New List(Of String)

        Using Connection As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)

            Connection.Open()

            Dim sqlString = "select customer from tblSODetails where promiseddate <= '" & CutoffDate.ToShortDateString & "' " &
                "group by customer order by customer"

            Dim command = New SqlCommand(sqlString, Connection)

            Dim dataReader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()

            While dataReader.Read()
                MapDataReader(dataReader, 2)
                CList.Add(Customer)
            End While

        End Using

        Return CList

    End Function

    Public Shared Function OpenList(ByVal CutoffDate As Date, ByVal Customer As String, ByVal ShipVia As String) As List(Of SalesOrder)
        Using context = New iTracContext
            Dim query = context.SalesOrders.Include("Inventory").Include("Part").AsQueryable
            query = query.Where(Function(s) s.PromisedDate <= CutoffDate)
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Customer) Then query = query.Where(Function(s) s.Customer = Customer)
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(ShipVia) Then query = query.Where(Function(s) s.ShipVia = ShipVia)
            Return query.OrderBy(Function(l) l.PromisedDate).ToList
        End Using
    End Function

    Public ReadOnly Property PartNumber As String
        Get
            If Part IsNot Nothing Then
                Return Part.NormalizedPartNumber
            Else
                Return Nothing
            End If
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property rtsOk As Integer?
        Get
            If Inventory IsNot Nothing Then
                Return Inventory.rts_ok
            Else
                Return Nothing
            End If
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property rtsHold As Integer?
        Get
            If Inventory IsNot Nothing Then
                Return Inventory.rts_hold
            Else
                Return Nothing
            End If
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property rtsRejected As Integer?
        Get
            If Inventory IsNot Nothing Then
                Return Inventory.rts_rejected
            Else
                Return Nothing
            End If
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property rtsOut As Integer?
        Get
            If Inventory IsNot Nothing Then
                Return Inventory.rts_out
            Else
                Return Nothing
            End If
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property rtsInReceving As Integer?
        Get
            If Inventory IsNot Nothing Then
                Return Inventory.rts_receiving
            Else
                Return Nothing
            End If
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property rtsInShipping As Integer?
        Get
            If Inventory IsNot Nothing Then
                Return Inventory.rts_in_shipping
            Else
                Return Nothing
            End If
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property rtsIssued As Integer?
        Get
            If Inventory IsNot Nothing Then
                Return Inventory.rts_issued
            Else
                Return Nothing
            End If
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: That's not the function that throws the exception. Before that function is called (the first time), a `Shared` field is being initialized in the type initializer, and *that* is throwing the exception. You need to show more of the `SalesOrder` class.

Comment: `sid = If(IsDBNull(dataReader("sid")), "", dataReader("sid"))` This has probably never come up because sid always has a value but if it is DBNull  I don't think you wand to assign an empty string to a decimal value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is throwing the exception:

```
Private Shared ConnectionString As String = BrowserUtilities.Settings.ConnectionString
```

Something in the expression `BrowserUtilities.Settings.ConnectionString` is throwing an exception.  It's unclear what it is but I would say that `NullReferenceException` is the most likely candidate.  Maybe `BrowserUtilities.Settings` is `Nothing`.  It's just guesswork at this point.  You'll have to debug it to find out.

---

When a `Shared` (`static` in C#) field, such as `ConnectionString` in your code, has an initialization expression, that initialization occurs in a special method called a "type initializer".  All initialization expressions for the `Shared` fields in a type are grouped into the type initializer and executed before the first time that type is used<sup>*</sup>.

<sup>*</sup>This is a slight simplification for the sake of this explanation.

The first time you called the `SalesOrdersByBody_JB` function, it first had to initialize the type, which means running the type initializer to initialize `ConnectionString`.  It looked like `SalesOrdersByBody_JB` threw the exception, but it was really happening *slightly* before that.

Comment: Looks like you are RIGHT(again!) I will start debugging! Thanks!

Comment: Found it! Settings had a select statement that popped up a message box and that threw the exception in the service! Good to know! I am getting into this service stuff! Thanks again! U da man!!!

Comment: Some additional advice: Properties should not be doing as much work as your `Settings` property is doing. A property should return a value you already have or a small calculation from values you already have. Doing a database query is *way* too much. Also, learn about layering. You should have a layer (e.g. class library) that's responsible for the core functionality. You can call that from a Windows Service process where output is logged to a file or a Windows Forms process where output is shown in a message box. This will help you avoid problems like this in the future.

Comment: And congratulations on successfully digging up the exception.